# sed command not updating text file

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, hp-ux

Would like to ask because I'm having an issue with sed command in unix scripting.

```
#!/bin/sh
cnt=2
sed '1 c\
$cnt' test.txt
```

I want to replace the first line of text file test.txt with the value of variable cnt which is 2. How can I pass the variable on the above sed command? The sed command treats $cnt as string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables are not expanded in single quotes. They are expanded in double quotes, though.

```
sed "1 c\\
$cnt" test.txt
```

Note that `sed` doesn't update the input file by default, it outputs the changed version instead. If your implementation of sed supports it, use the `-i` switch to modify the input file. Otherwise, you'd have to redirect the output to a new file and rename it back to the original name:

```
sed "..." text.txt > text.new
mv text.new text.txt
```

Comment: I got an error: "sed: Function 1 c2 cannot be parsed."

Comment: @user3051523: Sorry, you need to escape the backslash. Check the update.

Comment: It worked but the test.txt was not updated.

Comment: @user3051523: Have you read the whole answer?

Comment: thanks anyway, i guess I should use -i as you mentioned..

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
#!/bin/sh
cnt=2
sed "1 c\
$cnt" test.txt
```

For variable interpolation to happen, u need to put it within double quotes rather than single quotes.

Comment: I got an error: "sed: Function 1 c2 cannot be parsed." When I tried to change it from single to double quotes...

Comment: I m not getting that error, try changing it to sed "1 c $cnt" test.txt (in single line)

Comment: I'm still getting the error when I changed to:

Comment: sed "1 c $cnt" test.txt
also I tried:
sed "1 c\ $cnt" test.txt

Comment: sed "1 c ${cnt}" test.txt

I tried the above but still getting an error.